# Selection.Range Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have code that gets the range of each heading in a word document. The headings' ranges are saved in HeadingRange(). I am getting Run-Type Error 13: type mismatch when I set HeadingRange(HeadingCount) in my For loop. I don't know why this is happening. Both HeadingRange() and wrdApp.Selection.Range are clearly instances of the Range class.

```
Private Sub WordTab()

Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:/Test.docx")


Dim i As Integer 
Dim myHeadings As Variant
Dim count As Integer
Dim HeadingRange() As Range
Dim HeadingCount as Integer


TableCount = wrdDoc.Tables.count
wrdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory  'moves selection to beginning of doc. assuming document's first line is not a heading.
myHeadings = wrdDoc.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

HeadingCount = 1
For i = LBound(myHeadings) To UBound(myHeadings) 'iterate through all headings

    wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext 'move selection to next heading. 
    wrdApp.Selection.Expand wdLine 'expand selection range to entire line

    ReDim Preserve HeadingRange(1 To HeadingCount)
    Set HeadingRange(HeadingCount) = wrdApp.Selection.Range 'This is where the type mismatch happens
    HeadingCount = HeadingCount + 1


Next i

wrdDoc.Close (Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
Debug.Print "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are running this procedure from another application (Excel, maybe?). If so, try: `Dim HeadingRange() As Word.Range`

Answer (score 0):

Redimension the Array to some dummy size first. You are trying to `Preserve` a non-existent array.

So you could add a

```
Redim HeadingRange(1 To 1)
```

code at the start, before your loop begins.

Comment: I've added that to the beginning of the loop and I'm still getting the same error. I've also tried to get rid of the loop altogether and make HeadingRange a scalar Range variable and I still got the type error.

Comment: @user3805884, did David's solution work? in that case please close this q. Tks